# Not able to send response back to index.js in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am writing a code to connect to jira api and return jira status for the Jira-issue using node js, and facing a problem in getting the response back to the defined method. And the request is reaching time out.Here i am pasting my code .

**index.js code:**

```
 app.post('/GetJiraIssueStatus', async (req, res) => {
   var objinput = req.body
   var issuestatus
   issuestatus = require('./get_jira_issue_status.js')
   const response = await issuestatus.getStatus(objinput);
   console.log("outer: " + response)
   res.send(response)
 })
```

```
**get_jira_issue_status.js code**
```

```
    const JiraClient = require('jira-connector')
    const request = require('request')
    const output1 = { "status": "initializing" };    
    exports.getStatus = async function (JiraRequest) {
       console.log("issue:" + JiraRequest.issue)
       var issueNum = JiraRequest.issue
       var options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://jira.service.anz/rest/api/latest/issue/' + issueNum + '?expand=names,renderedFields',
          headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
       };

       process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
       const mmmm = request(options, async function (error, response, body) {
          console.log("sent request to jira")
          if (error) { console.log("we have an error"); throw new Error(error) }
          console.log('Response: ' + response.statusCode + ' ' + response.statusMessage);
          var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);
          let return_value = newFunction(jsonObj.fields.status.name);
          console.log("return value:" + return_value)
          return return_value;
       });
       console.log("mmmm is" + mmmm.fields.status.name);
    }

    logStatus = function (status) {
       output1.issueStatus = status;
    }

    function newFunction(response) {
       console.log("new function:" + response)
       return (response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see here is that your getStatus method is async so it is expected to return a promise which you are not returning. You can either use `request-promise` or wrap request in promise like this

```
 return new Promise.resolve((resolve, reject) => {
request(options, async function (error, response, body) {
          console.log("sent request to jira")
          if (error) { console.log("we have an error"); reject(error) }
          console.log('Response: ' + response.statusCode + ' ' + response.statusMessage);
          var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);
          let return_value = newFunction(jsonObj.fields.status.name);
          console.log("return value:" + return_value)
          resolve(return_value);
       });
});
```

By the way request package is not maintained any more. Better to use `axios`, `got` etc.

Answer (score 0):

// import this module
[module link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-request)

**const request = require('async-request');**

```
const JiraClient = require('jira-connector')
const request = require('async-request');
const output1 = { "status": "initializing" };    
exports.getStatus = async function (JiraRequest) {
   console.log("issue:" + JiraRequest.issue)
   let result;
   var issueNum = JiraRequest.issue
   var options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://jira.service.anz/rest/api/latest/issue/' + issueNum + '?expand=names,renderedFields',
      headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
      }
   };

   process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;

   try{
    result = await request(https://jira.service.anz/rest/api/latest/issue/' + issueNum + '?expand=names,renderedFields',options)
   } catch(error) {
         console.log("we have an error",error)
   }
      console.log("sent request to jira")

      console.log('result: ' + result.statusCode + ' ' + result.statusMessage);
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body);
      var return_value = newFunction(jsonObj.fields.status.name);
      console.log("return value:" + return_value)
      return return_value;
   console.log("mmmm is" + mmmm.fields.status.name);
}
```